# Getting error message while registering Android device with GCM and PushWoosh

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting  following logcat messages while registering the Android device using cordova push notification plugin.

```
01-25 19:33:34.871: V/GCMRegistrar(6495): Is registered on server: false
01-25 19:33:34.871: D/GCMRegistrar(6495): resetting backoff for com.example.homework
01-25 19:33:34.941: V/GCMRegistrar(6495): Registering app com.example.homework of senders 19845108581
01-25 19:33:35.011: D/memalloc(6495): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x534bb000 size:1536000 fd:90
01-25 19:33:35.011: D/CordovaLog(6495): report:deviceready
01-25 19:33:35.011: I/Web Console(6495): report:deviceready at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:122
01-25 19:33:35.162: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6495): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-25 19:33:35.162: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6495): GCM IntentService class: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService
01-25 19:33:35.172: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6495): Acquiring wakelock
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6495): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6495): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-25 19:33:35.192: I/GCMIntentService(6495): Received recoverable error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6495): Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 2788 (3000)
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/Socket_Alarm(6495): registerHTCSocketMonitorCallBack
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/Socket_Alarm(6495): set mSocketMonitor
01-25 19:33:35.192: D/Socket_Alarm(6495): HTCSocketMonitorImpl::HTCSocketMonitorImpl
01-25 19:33:35.352: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6495): Releasing wakelock
01-25 19:33:36.603: D/DroidGap(6495): onMessage(spinner,stop)
01-25 19:35:03.978: V/webview(6495): hitTestResult use fallback
```

I am setting the correct values for projectid and appid in javascript file. And also my android device is configured with Google account. I am following this guide 
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You got a "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" error. Perhaps your device wasn't connected to the internet at the time your App attempted to register, or perhaps the Google service was down (which is less likely).

Comment: No, the device has active internet connection via wifi and its working fine. I found that the error "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" comes under error 500-599 range (such as 500 or 503) which indicates that there was an internal error in the GCM server while trying to process the request, or that the server is temporarily unavailable.But I am continuously trying the service from more than 3-4 days and its showing same error.

Answer (score 3):

i got the same issue as u did, check for your device's internet connectivity. It might be slow and if it is, its not connecting ua device to the GCM server.